How can I turn nextjs app into a widget in webflow?
Has anyone widgetized a nextjs app for webflow, non iframe solution? Or embedded somewhere with cdn url?  I’m wondering what i need to do to deploy a static ui that can hit an api endpoint hosted somewhere else? Any insight or resource on t

Cheerio with Webflow will convert Webflow to Next JS (next js 13 pages file system-not app file stack)
https://dev.to/kennedyrose/integrating-webflow-and-next-js-39kk
